# Why does the Kryptonian space ship that is capable of genetic engineering fail to distinguish a kryptonian from a human?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In movies, the Superman's ship is shown to be very highly technologically advanced. In the latest Batman Vs Superman movie, it is shown to be capable of genetic re-engineering. Also, It is shown to have information regarding many galaxies etc. Why does a ship like that use very simple authentication techniques like 'S' logo pendant , 'fingerprints' etc ?

Comment: This might not be what you want to hear, but it could just be because that's the easiest to get across on screen.

Comment: @PointlessSpike - You misunderestimate how far ahead writers plan...

Comment: @Richard- I suspect that's not something they planned but an attempt to close a plothole.

Comment: @PointlessSpike - I find it moderately interesting that the ship recognises General Zod. That means he's been a general for more than 20,000 years, *before* the point that the Kryptonians gave up space exploration.

Comment: @Richard- Didn't it just recognise that his chip was valid? That just means it has a code that's been in use for all that time.

Comment: @pointlessspike - It seems to recognise him from his hand-print

Comment: @Richard- There could be some kind of FTL information network like Halo's Domain that it accesses (or at least synchronises with on occasion).

Comment: @pointlessspike - Except that Zod doesn't know about the ship until Clark activates it and there's no indication that there's anything left for it to get updates from.

Comment: @Richard Does Zod get information because Clark activates it? Doesnt Zod find the planet somehow in the movie? Is it different in the comics?

Comment: @AswinPJ- Zod explicitly states that Clark activating the ship was how he found Earth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [prequel comic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qult6.jpg) for Man of Steel informs us that the Kryptonian Scout Ship (the one at the crash site in Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice) was originally an exploration and terraforming vessel piloted by Captain Kara-El and her crew. Unbeknownst to her, a criminal known as [Dev-Em](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Dev-Em) had stowed away on board and took over by compromising the ship's internal system while the crew were in hypersleep. Apparently even at that point a hand-print was all that was required to give access to "everything".

Over the next decade it seems likely that if there were any other security features in place (biometric or otherwise), that Dev-em systematically stripped them out, leaving the ship entirely vulnerable to Luthor's ruse, 20,000 years later.

[image]

The fact that "Zod" is able to add another administration-level user **simply by asking the computer to do so** implies that the ship's security has been utterly compromised in a way that was never intended.

---

Note also that the ship's AI is capable of being ***reasoned with***. That in itself is a massive security fail...

> **Ship:** *It has been decreed by the Council of Krypton that none will ever again give life to a deformity so hateful to sighted memory.
>   The desecration without name.*
>
> **Lex:** *And where is the Council of Krypton?*
>
> **Ship:** *Destroyed, sir*
>
> **Lex:** *Then proceed.*
>
> **Ship:** *Very well.*

Comment: So basically, a single Kryptonian SysAdmin could've prevented all the events in the film.

Comment: @liesmith - yeah, pretty much. If we've  learned anything from these movies it's that Kryptonian infosec is really *really* crappy.